# Strange POST requests to my Ubuntu server - am I in trouble?

Tags: apache2, security, php

I have an Ubuntu Server 12.04 installed on a VM. This server has [apache2-mpm-prefork [image: Install apache2-mpm-prefork]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/apache2-mpm-prefork) and [libapache2-mod-php5 [image: Install libapache2-mod-php5]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libapache2-mod-php5) installed. I was looking through the logs and recently came across these rather suspicious entries:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [20/Jan/2014:09:00:04 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" 200 274 ...
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [20/Jan/2014:09:00:23 +0000] "POST /cgi-bin/php?%2D%64+...
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [20/Jan/2014:09:00:25 +0000] "POST /cgi-bin/php5?%2D%64...
...
```

Decoding the content after `php?...` results in the following:

```
-d allow_url_include=on -d safe_mode=off -d suhosin.simulation=on -d
  disable_functions="" -d open_basedir=none -d
  auto_prepend_file=php://input -d cgi.force_redirect=0 -d
  cgi.redirect_status_env=0 -n
```

Is this something I should be concerned about?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is probably a old Zero Day attack targeting Parallels Plesk Panel. If you are not running it, you should be pretty safe. [This is a quote about how the attack is done from Computer World](http://www.computerworld.com.my/print-article/36497/):

> A command executed by the exploit contains several arguments that are intended to disable security mechanisms that might exist on the server, he said. These include the “allow_url_include=on” argument which allows the attacker to include arbitrary PHP code and the “safe_mode=off” argument. “As a final step Suhosin, a PHP hardening patch, is put into simulation mode. This mode is designed for application testing, and effectively turns off the extra protection.”

In the POST request we can see the 3 vertices of the attack, which is in fact the first 3 commands sent `-d allow_url_include=on -d safe_mode=off -d suhosin.simulation=on`. The rest is just crawling more in your server.

You may want to know more about the [CVE-2012-1823](https://www.google.com/search?q=CVE-2012-1823) that address this issue. Parallels provided a [workaround to protect their users/costumers.](http://kb.parallels.com/en/113818) [This issue has been fixed in all versions of Ubuntu,](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2012/CVE-2012-1823.html) only old unmaintained servers are in danger. If you are using version equal or superior than 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.1 of php5-cgi, you are out of danger.